# Can any one tell me that how to sort time in javascript by using only sort() and then switch case()

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, object, quicksort

```
{"09:12p","08:00a","12:00a","04:00"}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Y0n.png)
1st try:

```
 case 'clockInEndTime':
    if (a.clockInEndTime.getTime().toString() == b.clockInEndTime.getTime().toString()) {
        return (new Date(a.scheduledStartDate || a.date) < new Date(b.scheduledStartDate || b.date)) ? -1 : (new Date(a.scheduledStartDate || a.date) > new Date(b.scheduledStartDate || b.date)) ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        return (a.clockInEndTime.getTime().toString() < b.clockInEndTime.getTime().toString()) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to sort that data structure I'd suggest first converting it to an array, otherwise you're making it more difficult that it needs to be. From there you need a method to parse those strings to dates. I'd suggest using MomentJS for this as the logic can be quite complex. From there it's a simple `sort()` call.

Comment: Please post the code that you tried even if not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), but you need to provide a function to create an objective measure of each timestamp. Below we convert to minutes, you could also do this with hours etc.

Once converted to a comparable measure of time elapsed in the day, we can use .sort() to either sort in ascending or descending order.

Note, we're shallow copying here using [...] to ensure we sort a copy of the array.

```js
const times = [ '10:00a', '11:00a', '12:00a', '01:00a', '02:00a'];

function timeToMinutes(input) {
    if (!input) {
        return 0;
    }
    let [_ ,hour, minute, meridiem ] = input.match(/(\d{1,2})\:(\d{1,2})([ap])?/i);
    hour = Number(hour) + (meridiem === 'p' ? 12: 0);
    return hour * 60 + Number(minute);
}

const sortedAsc = [...times].sort((a, b) => timeToMinutes(a) - timeToMinutes(b));
const sortedDesc = [...times].sort((a, b) => timeToMinutes(b) - timeToMinutes(a));

console.log('Sorted (ascending):', sortedAsc);
console.log('Sorted (descending):', sortedDesc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am already using the sort function and switch case to sort 60 columns. Can you please tell me a way to solve it using sort() only and inside the switch case only?

Comment: I tried it but it is showing error : TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefine

Comment: Is it possible one of the times is undefined or empty?

Comment: yes, it is possible.
somevalues of time are undefined or empty

Comment: And its working fine on the 12-hour format but when I am trying to apply it in 24 hr then it's not working.
I've two requirements that it should work on both 24 hr and 12 hr formats. 
and few time  values we are receiving are undefined or empty.
Can you please share the code according to that. 
Thankyou so much bytheway.

Comment: I've made a couple of changes, this should improve the behaviour of the function.

Comment: There is one last problem I am facing-
output:-{10:00a, 11:00a, 12:00a, 01:00a, 02:00a }
issue - Time 12:00a, 01:00a should come before Time 10:00 am.
Is it possible?  
we need to sort it according to time.

Comment: I updated the question to use the values above, e.g. 10:00a, 11:00a, 12:00a, 01:00a, 02:00a. They should sort in the desired order using an ascending sort.

Comment: one case is also their in different column - format is different 01:00p - 03:56p

Comment: Hi Terry it's working fine if all values coming in the column but its not working fine when their are some empty values even if set it to return 0.